# If $\mu(X) = \infty$ and for all $F \in {\cal E}$, there is $E \in {\cal E}$ such that $0 < \mu(E) < \mu(F)$, then $\mu$ is onto.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $(X, {\cal E}, \mu)$ is an infinite measure space (meaning that $\mu(X) = \infty$) with the property that for every $F \in {\cal E}$ with $\mu(F) >0$, there is an $E  \in {\cal E}$ such that $0 < \mu(E) < \mu(F)$.  Then the range of $\mu$ is all of $[0,\infty]$.

Any ideas on where to get started?

Comment: ?? If $F= \emptyset$, then it is impossible to find some $E  \in {\cal E}$ such that $ 0 < \mu(E) < \mu(F).$

Comment: Great point, perhaps there is a missing assumption.

Comment: I think you want $E\in\mathcal E$ such that $0\lt\mu(E)\lt\mu(F)$ ***and*** $E\subset F$. Otherwise your hypothesis is too weak and there are easy counterexamples.

Comment: Could you construct a counter example?

Comment: For example, say $X=\mathbb Z$ and $\mathcal E=\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mu(\{n\})=1$ for $n\le0$ and $\mu(\{n\})={10}^{-n}$ for $n\gt0$.